# How can I reduce the number of parameters in this function

Tags: python, function

I've been reading *Clean Code* by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob) which states that functions should have as few parameters as possible. Ideally zero.

The book suggests that three or more parameters is too many for a function.

I am now trying to implement this practice into my own code and I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the number of parameters in the following function

```
def json_return(
    status_code
    message
    data = None,
    headers = None,
):
    payload = {"status_code": status_code, "message": message}
    if data:
        payload.update({"data": data})
    response = jsonify(payload), status_code, headers
    return response
```

This is a function used to generate a JSON response. I'm having troubling understanding how to structure this function in a way that it takes fewer parameters.

One thought I had was to make this into a `Response` class but I would still need to initialize that class with these same arguments as far as I can tell.

How can I better organize this function so that it takes fewer arguments. The solution can be splitting it into multiple functions, a larger class or anything else (it isn't restricted to keeping it as one function).

EDIT: **I know these principals are controversial. I understand that and still want to learn how best to implement them in my code.**

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. My opinion is that the advice you're trying to follow is misguided, or at least not useful for all programming paradigms. For strict OO programming, removing parameters is important; for strict functional programming, there's no way to do anything _without_ parameters. You should use as many parameters as are necessary to do what you need to, and no more than that.

Comment: Ah thank you, I'll repost there. I understand some of these rules are controversial, but I'm trying to learn them nonetheless before forming my own opinion

Comment: *"The book suggests that three or more parameters is too many for a function."* seems a bit excessive of a rule. Most of the functions in the code that I work on have many parameters.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: He wrote that or java, not for Python, because he doesn't understand Python. In python you would write a method (on a class), like `as_json` (similar to `as_dict`) and don't worry about it, because it just works. Unlike Java, in Python a object is like a dict, so conversion is not an issue, and does not require some extra layer with conversion logic.